# Sync aws s3 bucket (along with folder structure) on local and run python code only on newly added local folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm reading logs (which are in compressed `.gz` file) from source S3 bucket. The `.gz` files are present in folder inside s3 bucket which looks like below (folder are created based on unix epoch time, 1 folder per day)

```
1540684800000 (1 folder/day contains multiple .gz file)  
1541462400000  
1542240000000  
1543104000000
```

Now I've to run below python code to make these `.gz` file in proper json array format. The data and structure inside single `.gz` file is as below. The json array is missing outer brackets [ ] and comma(,) between two json array (after `"version":2`} ). There is a new line (`\n`) character separating two json array records.

```
{"context":"abc","event":"login","timestamp":"2018-09-27T17:35:55.835Z","version":2}
{"context":"def","timestamp":"2018-09-27T17:35:55.835Z","Id":"faf91826-ebc9-4242-996f-d52969bec2d5","version":2}
{"context":"xyz","event":"LandingPage","timestamp":"2019-01-21T05:14:22.998Z","Id":"88016b33-72d7-458e-8de8-f76241f4b681","version":2}
```

For now i've manually decompressed the `.gz` files and then renamed them to `.json` (through unix commands). And will be running below python code to make these files in proper json format -

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import re

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk ('/user/home/src/'):
    for file in files:
        path = subdir + os.sep + file
        if not(path.endswith('.DS_Store')):
            print(file)
            jsonFile = open(path,"r")
            text = jsonFile.read()
            jsonFile.close()

            #working with buffered content
            #text = "["+text+"]"
            pattern = re.sub(r'}(\s*){', r'},\1{', text) 

            ## Save changes to JSON file
            jsonFile = open(path, "w+")
            data = "["+json.loads(json.dumps(pattern))+"]"
            jsonFile.write(data)
            jsonFile.close()
```

I need to copy source `.gz` files locally and run above python code to make them in proper json array format and upload them to target s3 bucket. I'm beginner in python and need help with -

a) how do i daily sync source s3 bucket on local and run python code only on newly added folder (inside the local copy) . And upload new folder on target s3 bucket daily.
b) how can i drop/remove json records with missing "event" attribute (in this case second record) , while i convert the file into proper json array.
c) can i append json records from multiple .gz files and have one json array (with .json extension). So i have single .json file for each day.

Expected Output in json file:

```
[{"context":"abc","event":"login","timestamp":"2018-09-27T17:35:55.835Z","version":2},
{"context":"xyz","event":"LandingPage","timestamp":"2019-01-21T05:14:22.998Z","Id":"88016b33-72d7-458e-8de8-f76241f4b681","version":2}]
```

Comment: Through aws documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), for ``` aws s3 sync ``` , looks like i can get newly added folder inside s3 bucket on my local. Now I would have to figure out way to keep track of folders on local which are already modified through above python code and the new ones received after ``` aws s3 sync ``` - whose files needs to be made in proper json array format. Please suggest ?

Comment: @Milan Cermak, can you please suggest/provide inputs

Comment: It looks like there is a missing closing curly brace on each line of your example input.  Is that a typo or legit what it looks like?

Comment: @KevinSeaman - Corrected the typo in example input. So each line in example input has the closing curly brace. Thanks for point it out.